# freeglut (something): failed to open display ''

Tags: linux, freeglut

I compiled a C++ code under Linux (Ubuntu) and everything is fine as far as I connect a monitor to my PC.

My code shows some graphics and then it saves their screenshots. The runtime graphic is not important to me but the screenshots.

But if I run the code remotely, I face with the following runtime error:

> freeglut (something): failed to open display ''

If I forward x (`ssh -v -X`) everything would be find. But what if I don't do that?!

How to get around it? I don't care if anything is displayed or not.
Is it possible to define a temporary virtual screen on the remote computer or get around this problem in any other way? I just need the screenshot files.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on this, but I believe that you'd want to just create the GL context without creating a window. Don't define the read/write parameters at first, create some FBOs, then set those FBOs as the read/write buffers. This way the context still has default buffers, but doesn't require a window for them. Check out [this link](https://community.khronos.org/t/offscreen-rendering-without-a-window/57842/4)

Comment: As far as I'm aware it's not possible to create a GL context without a window. In all the projects I've worked on it has always been necessary to have a window (hidden is possible) to create a GL context.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try XVFD as your X server on the remote machine

Quote form this answer: [Does using Xvfb to run OpenGL effects version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521682/does-using-xvfb-to-run-opengl-effects-version)

> Xvfb is an X server which whole purpose is to provide X11 services without having dedicated graphics hardware

This allows you to have both a GL context and a window without using a GPU