# Does using Xvfb to run OpenGL effects version?

Tags: linux, opengl, driver, freeglut, xvfb

I'm trying to run OpenGL on headless ubuntu server.

- GPU / Driver : NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1080Ti / version 418.67
- Using `freeglut` (installed by running `apt install freeglut3-dev`)
- Using `Xvfb` (Since it is a headless server.)

When I run `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`, it says `OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.2.8`. So, I am unable to run a code that requires OpenGL 3.3.

Since driver 418.67 is not latest, I could consider updating the driver, but I wanted to make sure if this could do something with `Xvfb`. Can using `Xvfb` can effect the driver and the OpenGL version it supports when I make a gl context with `Xvfb` running? Or it has nothing to do with it and only thing I can do is updating the driver?

Answer (score 4):

Xvfb is an X server which whole purpose is to provide X11 services without having dedicated graphics hardware (i.e. a GPU). So it's the exact opposite of what you want.

Either don't use X11 at all and create a headless EGL OpenGL context: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/

Or use the "regular" Xorg server on the GPU without a display and input devices attached (you actually might want to disable automatic input device attachment in the configuration).

Personally I'd go with headless EGL.

Comment: The code I want to run uses `glut`. (python `OpenGL.GLUT`).  
Is it possible to use headless EGL context easily with the code written with `glut`? 
 
Or could you point me to more information about the second option (regular Xorg server without display and input devices) ?  
Thank you for your response!

Comment: What do I do if I don't have a GPU for a game?

Comment: @bjcullinan I think I don't fully understand your question. Normally you'd want to run a game on a screen – and not in a headless environment at Xvfb is creating. If your remark is about running games without a GPU, then this the wrong question to address. Xvfb is meant for providing a graphical environment on systems that don't have display attach to at all (think servers, cloud VMs, stuff like that).